# Export the html to word with headers and footers and images (base64 encoded)

Tags: javascript, jquery, htmldoc

I need to export the content of html to word file along with headers and footers and also images.I have used the googoose.js code it works but this is not exporting images,which are base64 images and exporting normal images

```
<html>

<head>
<title> Word document </title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.googoose.js"></script>

<style>
    #googoose-footer {
        margin-right: 1in;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: right; 
    }
    #googoose-header {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>



<style>
#btnExport
{
        width: 60%;
    height: 30px;
    background: #5090a9;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 2px #ddd;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#btnDiv
{

float: right;
    width: 10%;
    *border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 15px;
}

#cnt-dv
{
    padding:15px;
    text-align:justify;

}
#hello-canvas
{
display:none;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div align="right" id="btnDiv">

<input type="button" name="btnExport" id="btnExport" value="getDoc">
</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class='googoose-wrapper'>
    <div class='googoose header'>
       -----Header-----
    </div>
<br>
<br>
its often a challenge to identify the right set of tools and technologies to execute a project of business interest as the factors influencing the decision are multiple and complex. STSI specializes in analyzing the client’s business use case, scenario, environment, target audience and budget to propose the right blend of technologies, tools, infrastructure and resources that may be required to address the client needs. We are committed to Empower Our Clients From Ideas to Applications with a methodical approach.
Softthink Solutions (STSI) is an emerging, innovative IT services partner who provides end-to-end project solutions and premium class services in Business Intelligence, Artificial Intelligence, Data Integration, Cybersecurity, Cloud Services and Application Development.
Located just outside Washington D.C., Softthink is uniquely positioned with a highly skilled team of professionals who come equipped with a wide array of skillsets to address your technical needs.
Regardless of the size of your business or the scope of your project, our technical team will work with you to create a solution that makes good business sense and return on investment. We offer a broad spectrum of proactive IT solutions which can be customised for your needs, and with our flexible solutions and Agile Development sensibilities, we will deliver the right end result, on time. We partner with our clients to identify, design and automate repeatable processes and workflows, offering accuracy and seamless operation, and we can respond quickly with service and solutions when unexpected crises occur, helping avert incidents that would otherwise disrupt your business workflow.
Service-oriented, world class service providers
Broad skillset and expertise backed by experience to address your expectations
Ability to customize solutions and applications tailored to your specific needs
Focus on continuous improvement of our resources, skills and processes.

<br>


<img src="123.png">

Located just outside Washington D.C., Softthink is uniquely positioned with a highly skilled team of professionals who come equipped with a wide array of skillsets to address your technical needs.
Regardless of the size of your business or the scope of your project, our technical team will work with you to create a solution that makes good business sense and return on investment. We offer a broad spectrum of proactive IT solutions which can be customised for your needs, and with our flexible solutions and Agile Development sensibilities, we will deliver the right end result, on time. We partner with our clients to identify, design and automate repeatable processes and workflows, offering accuracy and seamless operation, and we can respond quickly with service and solutions when unexpected crises occur, helping avert incidents that would otherwise disrupt your business workflow.
Service-oriented, world class service providers
Broad skillset and expertise backed by experience to address your expectations
Ability to customize solutions and applications tailored to your specific needs
Focus on continuous improvement of our resources, skills and processes.

<br>
<br>
 <canvas id='hello-canvas'></canvas>

    <div class='googoose footer'>
    -------Copy-Rights-Reserved@2018-------
        Page <span class='googoose currentpage'></span>
        of <span class='googoose totalpage'></span>
    </div>
</div>


</body>


</html>

<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnExport").click(function(e) {   
    var canvas = document.getElementById("hello-canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    function r(ctx, x, y, w, h, c) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(x, y, w, h);
      ctx.strokeStyle = c;
      ctx.stroke();
    }
    r(ctx, 0, 0, 32, 32, "black");
    r(ctx, 4, 4, 16, 16, "red");
    r(ctx, 8, 8, 16, 16, "green");
    r(ctx, 12, 12, 16, 16, "blue"); 


    var o = {
        download: 0,
        filename: 'test.doc'
    };
    $(document).googoose(o);
    });
});


</script>
```

works fine but not exporting images when img src is like

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQAAAAEACAMAAABrrFhUAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAD... ">
```

And I have tried FileSaver.js and wordexport.js 
but these are not allowing to fix header and footer.
Please give me any suggestion to resolve this issue

Comment: I guess you can't automate it without any serverside. You might try to use some converter from base64 to images.
There are a lot of online solutions, btw, for example - [this](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter)

Comment: I have used php also, with googoose the base64 source images are not exporting to doc other than this everything works fine.I need to export base64 source images to word with button click along with headers and footers